# Query Plan showing incorrect Results in Dev console. Please help/Suggest

Tags: apex, query, queryplan

[image: Screenshot of the Query Plan and Developer Console]

Why it is showing 2 different results when clicking on Query Plan button it shows cardinality 671 but the same query I executed it then the results are only 87 records? What exactly is the Cardinality/Sobject Cardinality?

[image]

Comment: Do you have deleted accounts? Note the "note" about "IsDeleted". This might be the source of other records being counted here.

Comment: I entered isdeleted =true as well as isDelete=false but in both of the queries I didn't get what is shown in the query plan.

Comment: You need to update your SOQL to use "ALL ROWS" to ensure that deleted records are included in the SOQL output (and here you can then distinguish between normal and deleted records using the `IsDeleted` value). See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_query_all_rows.htm)

Comment: ALL ROWS cant be executed in Query Editor. So how will i check.

Comment: Run the following anonymous apex: `System.debug([SELECT COUNT() FROM Account WHERE Phone != NULL ALL ROWS]);` then find the USER_DEBUG line in the debug output to see how many `Account` records there are, deleted or not, with a defined `Phone` field value.

Comment: Hi Phil , it has the same result.. it is returning 87 only. Have uploaded the debug log Image. Please check and suggest. I think it is a bug in Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334796&type=1&mode=1):

> **Cardinality**
> The estimated number of records that the leading operation type would return.
> For example, the number of records returned if using an index table.
>
> **sObject Cardinality**
> The approximate record count for the queried object.

So what your query plan tells you is you have 745 `Account` records in your org, 671 of which match the leading operation in your query.

Comment: Thanks but I ran a query without filter and it shows 760 total Accounts in my org with or without ALL ROWS. Total Count is 760.  As per you said 671 records matched the criteria then in my normal query also it should fetch 671. Shouldn't it?

Comment: Your leading operation is `Table Scan`. That operation only considered 671 records.

Comment: Oh. But if it is not considering the filter criteria and scanning the whole table then I am sorry I am not able to understand why it can't fetch 760 records because this count is also without any filters.